# Zen sub theme: page--node--name.tpl.php not working!

Tags: theming

I'm hoping someone can help me because I'm at my wits end!  I'm using the zen theme - then created a sub-theme and now I can't seem to get the custom templates to be recognized by the custom content type name (page--node--custom_content_name.tpl.php).

I've created a new template.php in my sub-theme and placed text that I've found in other blogs and forums to help make it recognize the content type so I can use it in the tpl.php name but nothing seems to work.  If I use the dev module it only says that I can name them page--node--1.tpl.php, which would be fine if we weren't going to be adding more content on an ongoing basis.

Right now I have so many tpl.php just so that I can show people what the pages will look like - it's crazy!! What am I doing wrong?!
Help!!

Comment: It looks like you are combining two content types (page & node). Are you trying to modify pages or nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal doesn't provide content type based template suggestions for `page.tpl.php` but for `node.tpl.php`. That means you can use a template like `node--custom-content-name.tpl.php`.

However, if you want to have a page.tpl.php for your content type, you need to tell Drupal about your template suggestion. Put this code in your `template.php` file:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['node']->type)) {
    $content_type = $variables['node']->type;
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $content_type;
  }
}
```

You should name your template file like: `page--custom-content-name.tpl.php`.

Comment: Thanks I've tried that too.  It still won't work and the devel module isn't showing that it's even possible to name the templates with the content type.  so I must be missing some PHP somewhere... I just don't know what.

Comment: my devel module shows me my options are this: Template called:
    sites/all/themes/mazin_theme/templates/page.tpl.php
Candidate template files:
    page--node--31.tpl.php < page--node--%.tpl.php < page--node.tpl.php < page.tpl.php

Comment: Ok, I thought Zen theme would provide those template suggestions for page.tpl.php but it is not the case as I read. AdaptiveTheme has an option to activate those template suggestions. In your case you should tell Drupal about them manually. I have updated my answer, please check.

Comment: Yup - that's it!  I just had to create a new template.php and put it in my sub-theme and the only thing in it was a slightly different version: function mazin_theme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    // - page--example.tpl.php 

if (isset($vars['node'])) {
$vars['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'page__'.$vars['node']->type; //
}
}